# How do I play a sound just once when the cursor enters my button?

Tags: xna, c#

I want to play a sound when the mouse is within the bounds of a button. When I first did it, it was just a constant sound no stoppages. But I then did it through a SoundEffectInstance, which just repeats the sound over and over while the mouse is within the bounds of the button. I've gotten to play it once. However, say that I would put my mouse over the play button, it would play the sound, but if I put it over the play button again it wouldn't play. So the sound would just play once of each button. I basically just want it to play once if the cursor is over a button. Then play again if the cursor goes over another/same button.

SoundManger class

```
    static SoundEffect selected;
    static SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance;

    public static void Initialize(ContentManager Content) 
    {
        try
        {
            selected = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sound Effects/SelectSound");
            soundEffectInstance = selected.CreateInstance();
        }
        catch 
        {
            Debug.Write("SoundManager failed to Initialize");
        }

    }

    public static void PlaySelected() 
    {
        try
        {  
             soundEffectInstance.Play();   
        }
        catch 
        {
            Debug.Write("Selected sound failed");
        }
    }
```

Update Method for Button.cs

```
if (btnRect.Contains(mousePosition))
        {
            btnCol.R = 62;
            btnCol.G = 85;
            btnCol.B = 91;

            if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
             clicked = true;

             SoundManager.PlaySelected();
        }
        else
        {
            btnCol.R = 255;
            btnCol.G = 255;
            btnCol.B = 255;

            clicked = false;
        }
```

Comment: I'm betting if you wrote this out on paper or thought about it a little more, you'd be able to figure it out. The button has a `played` variable, as long as it's `true` the sound won't play again. So, just reset the `played` value to `false` when the mouse leaves the button.

Comment: This is a relatively simple answer and I agree with @Byte56 that a very short Google search would have found the answer here.

Comment: Don't forget to let us know if it has helped you, we always like to hear an update, even on the small questions

Comment: Sorry dudes, forgot to give you an update. Yeah I managed to get it working, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

As per @Byte56's and my comment, this is quite a simple solution even without using any xna sound manager variables. Use a property or variable in your button or whatever handles the button update to flag when the sound is played and whether that sound should be played again.

```
if (btnRect.Contains(mousePosition))
{
    btnCol.R = 62;
    btnCol.G = 85;
    btnCol.B = 91;

    //set played as true (you can create this variable yourself)
    if (!soundPlayed) {
        SoundManager.PlaySelected();
        soundPlayed = true;
    }

    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed){
        clicked = true;
    }
}
else
{
    btnCol.R = 255;
    btnCol.G = 255;
    btnCol.B = 255;

    played = false; // reset once mouse leaves button
    clicked = false;
}
```